# ActiveMQ Artemis login in web console fail

Tags: activemq-artemis

Login works with SSL and Active Directory. However, login with HTTP and local admin fails without error message. The web console just returns to the login screen. Also, the log says user authenticated. We're using Artemis 2.27.0.

bootstrap.xml:

```xml
<web path="web">
    <binding uri="https://host1:sslport" keyStorePath="XXXXX" keyStorePassword="xxxxx">
        <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
        <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
        <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
    </binding>
    <binding uri="http://host1:port">
        <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
        <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
        <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
    </binding>
</web>
```

login.config

```
activemq {
    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule sufficient
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";

    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.LDAPLoginModule sufficient
-- The rest is secret --´
```

`artemis.profile` is default except for:

```
HAWTIO_ROLE='amq,LDAP_artemis_instance_admin,LDAP_artemis_admin'
```

´
Log
2022-12-20 14:52:53,822 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Logging in user: user1

Audit
2022-12-20 14:52:53,824 AUDIT AMQ601715: User user1(LDAP_Application_Artemis_Admin)@xx.x.xx.xx:xxxxx successfully authenticated
´

Comment: Can you also paste the log message which indicates the user is authenticated?

Comment: Login with https works with local admin.

Comment: artemis.profile is default except:
HAWTIO_ROLE='amq,LDAP_artemis_instance_admin,LDAP_artemis_admin'